# DNS A records updated 3 days ago - new ip not updating

Tags: domain-name-system

As mentioned in the title I have instructed my client to update their DNS A records to point to my new server IP 3 days ago. The domain registrar is Heart Internet and the client has provided me with an actual screenshot of the page showing that the (*, @, www) A records have indeed been pointed to my new server but I am seeing no change in any DNS records using various tools such as whatsmydns.

The old and new servers are both running Ubuntu 12. The old server is running using Nginx while the new one is running using Apache2.

I am clueless as to why this is happening because using another registrar I have successfully updated DNS records for other clients which all point to the new server correctly.

If I am not able to solve the problem using advice I will provide the IP/domain name here.

Comment: The most likely reason for this is that the serial number on the zone hasn't been changed - so the previous entry is being cached. When you do an 'nslookup' on the SOA does it give the right answer?

Comment: Pinging the SOA using 'nslookup' gives me a timeout. Very strange, I have used the SOA record from the information gathered using the site 'intoDNS'

EDIT: I would also like to note that the SOA that 'intoDNS' gives me for my clients domain is different from the one that is in the records (for ns1) from the client provided screenshot.

Comment: can you tell domain name and what configuration have you done so far..

Comment: The domain name is usspeaking.com and so far the DNS A records for (*, @, www) have been pointed towards the new server.

Comment: ip is this 162.13.85.23?

Comment: Yes, that is the old server IP.

Comment: it seems that your ip address is not yet pointing to new one and your dns records are ns59.1and1.co.uk.,ns60.1and1.co.uk.,i think thats also pointing to old server right?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Should I be instructing the client to change the ns1/ns2 records to some other IP? Or is that IP dependent on the domain registrar?

Comment: yes you have to.please look into the answer provided below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not uncommon for the name servers to exist somewhere other than the Registrar. Many web hosting companies tell customers to move their name servers to the web hosting company (some may even require it although there's no technical requirement for a web host to also host the DNS). Many "individual" web hosters also tell their customers to move their name servers (foolishly, because web hosters aren't typically good at hosting DNS and probably shouldn't do so).

The key is to update the A record at the DNS host that is authoritative for the domain. Right now, that appears to be `ns59.1and1.co.uk` and `ns60.1and1.co.uk`. So your client should have a login for 1and1 so that they can edit the A record there. If they don't then they'll need to contact 1and1 to get a login. I'm assuming that 1and1 hosted their web site at one point. Your client could also move their name servers back to the Registrar. They'll need a login at the Registrar to do that.

**EDIT**

This is a topic that I find confuses a lot of people so I'd like to clarify a few things:

When a domain name is registered there are typically four major components/entities involved:

**1.** The Registrar - This is where the domain is registered. The Registrar has ultimate authority of the domain name (registration, renewal, suspension).

**2.** DNS Host - This is where the name servers and DNS zone and records exist. What name servers are authoritative for the domain name?

**3.** Web Site - Where does the web site exist?

**4.** Email - Where does email for the domain go?

In today's market where providers want to "be all things to all people" it's not uncommon to have a single entity handle all four of these components, **but there's no technical requirement to do so**.

For example: I have several domain names registered via Network Solutions. Network solutions is the registrar and if I so choose they can also host my DNS namespace (the DNS zone for my domain name - this is where the authoritative name servers are), they could also host my web site and my email if I so choose. **But that's not a requirement**. I happen to have my DNS zone (again, the authoritative name servers) hosted at DynDNS. I host my web sites and my email myself. So you see that in my case there are three different entities involved: `1.` Network Solutions, who is the Registrar. `2.` DynDNS, who hosts the DNS zone for my domain. `3.` Me, who hosts my web sites and my email.

The point of all of this being: the name servers can be hosted by anyone who provides that service. It does not have to be the Registrar. It can be, and often is, the entity that hosts the web site. In your case it looks like 1and1 hosted the web site at some point and probably had the customer move their name servers to 1and1.

Comment: Indeed I was confused about this as I am new to the area. The information you provided is greatly appreciated. So if I understand correctly the A records need to be updated from 1and1 and not Heart Internet? I am saying this as the client provided me with a screenshot for A records from Heart Internet which is why I am confused as to where the A record needs to be updated from.

Comment: Yes, they need to be updated at 1and1. 1and1 is listed as the authoritative name servers for that domain name. That's why you're having trouble. The client edited the records at Heart Internet, but Heart Internet is not authoritative for the DNS zone.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. The client updated the records at 1and1 and problem is solved, and I now have a better understanding!

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 2):

Confirm from your client about the configuration if you don't have the access to do them by yourself. IP address is required for A record entry and dns is also required for domain name resolving. Both of them should be pointing correctly.And also its depend upon TTL time (how much time it will take to propagate).

Currently dig command shows this if its already been three days ,you have consult client about it.

> ;; ANSWER SECTION: usspeaking.com.  21561 IN A 162.13.85.23
>   ;; ANSWER
>   SECTION: usspeaking.com.  21599 IN NS ns59.1and1.co.uk.
>   usspeaking.com.  21599 IN NS ns60.1and1.co.uk.

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for your help, the A records as mentioned before are pointed to my new server. However, I cannot understand where to point the ns1/ns2 A records to. It appears that the nameserver records are pointed to another registrar rather than the one where the domain is registered at!

Answer (score 1):

Your current DNS pointing to old server DNS as mentioned in comment(ns59.1&1.co.uk , ns60.1&1.co.uk ).You should ask the hosting provider of new server about the DNS records and edit the DNS record entry according to that. Mostly its as ns1.my domain.com and ns2.my domain.com. They will fix it for you. This needs to be done from both ends(domain registrar side and hosting provider side).

Comment: Please tell the reason for downvote

Answer (score 0):

It is unusual not to resolve A record for 3 days maximum propagation takes 24-48 hours to be resolved. please confirm the DNS configuration with your client. if your domain registrar is not your hosting provider then you need to have your A record at your DNS zone of the hosting provider.